# Getting unknown property error on Yii2 model filter

Tags: php, yii2

On making a join in yii2 model and apply filter on it, gives me an error Getting unknown property: common\models\Application::

```
$filters=(object)json_decode($_GET['filters']);

$model = Application::find()
            ->distinct()
            ->join('LEFT JOIN', 
                   'profile_detail', 
                   'profile_detail.account_id = application.account_id')
            ->where(['post_id' => 62]);
$model->orFilterWhere(['like', 'profile_detail.institude_name', $filters->institude]);

return $model->all();
```

PS: On writing direct query instead of model its work fine.

Comment: So what exact unknown property is mentioned in error? You wrote just class name. Also I don't get why converting to object and `json_decode` is needed?

Comment: There is no property mention in the exception. Just 
**Getting unknown property: common\models\Application::
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php**

Comment: You have to provide more information.